# Why doesn't assigning two concatenated strings to another string work?

Tags: java, string

I was experimenting with the `String` class in Java and wanted to override the `toString()` method when I came across this issue. I did something like -

```
public class String1 {

private String s = "Hello World";

public static void main(String[] args) {

    String1 s1 = new String1();
    System.out.println(s1.s.toString());
}

public String toString() {
    String1 s2 = new String1();
    s2.s = this.s + " lel";
    return s2.s;
}

}
```

Output -

`Hello World`.

How do I modify it so that the `toString()` method outputs

`Hello World lel`

Comment: You are calling the `toString()` method on your inner string instead of your custom class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `s1.toString()` instead of `s1.s.toString()`

`s` is a instance of `String`

`s1` is an instance of `String1` [Your class]

You have defined `toString()` for your `String1`.

Answer (score 1):

you are invoking `String`'s `toString()` here by following

```
System.out.println(s1.s.toString());
```

to use `String1`'s `toString()` use

```
System.out.println(s1.toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply call `s1.toString());` instead of `s1.s.toString());`